# The unmodified round-shaped corner area in title bar above activity_main layout content

Tags: android, android-layout

**Round corner title layout**

[image]

I created an app project from Android Studio by choosing the "empty views" template and found that the area in the title bar contains a round-shaped corner background layout in Android 14 emulator, which is never gone away after changing the theme style or replacing the parent activity from AppCompatActivity to Activity.

I tried to use layout inspector to check the view properties and confirm that it is not related to the layout of main activity because there is no such layout in old Android releases. I want to know how I can remove this layout or style in android project?

After comparing with brand new template project, it seems that I've messed up with the Gradle deps and it might be the reason that the content view does not fit to the main window.

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```